# Mustache flat array into nested elements

Tags: javascript, json, template-engine, mustache

I'm isolating the problem and creating a simple case in here. It's basically an Image Accordion (CSS3 animation based) and in order to use this plugin my HTML structure has to be nested as shown below. In their samples the HTML was hardcoded - I need to use JSON data to generate the output.

Suppose an object like this,

```
[{imageurl:"link1"}, {imageurl: "link2"}, {imageurl: "link3"}]
```

I want the output to be

```
<figure>
    <img src="link1" />
    <figure>
        <img src="link2" />
        <figure>
           <img src="link3 />
        </figure>
    </figure>
 </figure>
```

I'm trying to think what kind of template can help to achieve this?

Comment: is a pure javascript solution possible without the use of a mustache template?

Comment: ah I wish I could get mustache to do it, so you mean to say it's not possible in mustache?

Comment: No, I don't mean to say that.  I've just never used mustache before and it seems like such a simple scenario that javascript could easily handle it.  It's not a solution because it doesn't use mustache but here's what I came up with using javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/LnVpg/1.  It's probably best to wait for someone who works with mustache to answer, though. edit: oops.  forgot to save a change to fix the tree structure.

Comment: interesting but I found an empty <figure> element at the end in the source code, please review

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to save it.  I noticed that too.  I updated my comment

Comment: It would be impossible in pure Mustache. Since it strives to be logicless, you can iterate through an array of data..but it output the *same* content for each item (i.e., you won't be able to nest "deeper" into the `figure` elements)..

Comment: Turns out even my second version was unnecessarily complex.  Here is the final version with comments of at least how I would do it with javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/LnVpg/2/

Comment: Thanks Joseph and Sam, I'm using jsfiddle.net/LnVpg/2

Comment: @user2727195 What library are you using for your templates? Mustache.js?

Comment: @Whymarrh yes Mustache.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Mustache language is "logic-less", views that require logic or complex nesting may need to be broken up into different views and included via partials or created outside of Mustache and then reinserted.

Anyhow, one way to produce the view that you desire is by reversing the array and working inside-out to nest the figures ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54DtU/)):

```
<!-- If your desired output is so:
<figure>
    <img src="link1">
    <figure>
        <img src="link2">
        <figure>
           <img src="link3">
        </figure>
    </figure>
 </figure>
-->
<script id="entriesTemplate" type="text/x-mustache-template">
    <figure>
        <img src="{{{imageurl}}}">
        {{{figure}}}
    </figure>
</script>
```

You can then nest the above template via a small snippet of JS:

```
var figs = [
    {url: "http://placehold.it/10x10"},
    {url: "http://placehold.it/10x10"},
    {url: "http://placehold.it/10x10"}
];

var ft = document.querySelector('#entriesTemplate').innerText.trim();
Mustache.parse(ft);

console.log(
    figs.slice(0) // Make a copy of the array as the next call to `.reverse()` will work in situ
        .reverse()
        .reduce(function (previous, current, index, array) {
            return fig = Mustache.render(ft, {
                imageurl: current.url,
                figure: previous
            });
        }, undefined)
);
```

When you pass `undefined` into the first template render, Mustache will produce no nested figure. Each subsequent render you are passing the output from the past to the outer figure etc. Instead of logging the value, you can then insert the chunk of HTML as need.

Comment: seems cool, I didn't get on first section <figure>...</figure> template, can we put this inside <script type=template></script> tag and then call parse on it

Comment: @user2727195 I'm not sure what you mean? Yes, you can treat the template as any other.

Comment: I'm editing the section 1 to describe, please edit the answer accordingly

Comment: @user2727195 I've updated the answer to clarify that yes you can put the template inside a `script` tag.

Comment: Note as well that the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54DtU/) link had an example of the template in action.

Comment: just one more request, can I've some kind of index generated as well, <img src="{{{imageurl}}}" id="image_0"> ... <img src="{{{imageurl}}}" id="image_1"> ... <img src="{{{imageurl}}}" id="image_2"> etc.

Comment: worked out, used index: array.length - index - 1, inside return fig = function  ...